# How can I wake up my PC with any key?

Tags: keyboard, suspend, input-devices

My external keyboard does not have a suspend button. Is there a way I can set up Ubuntu to use a different key (or any key for that matter) to wake the PC if it has been suspended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run the following command, you will see a list of USB devices and if they are enabled to wake up the system.

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

You will see a list of items such as the the one seen below.

```
USB0      S3    *disabled   pci:0000:00:12.0
```

Once you have established which device is the keyboard, let’s say *USB0*, run this command.

```
sudo su
echo USB0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Now, if you run the command from the start again, you should see *enabled* next to the device.

```
USB0      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:12.0
```

That worked for me, and I can wake up my desktop with any key.

Details on the wakeup codes for devices can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236127/acpi-wakeup-4-letters-code-meaning) (link courtesy of [Santhana Krishnan](https://askubuntu.com/users/918669/santhana-krishnan)).

Comment: It worked like a charm - Thank you very much. My USB keyboard was called UAR1, so I suppose chances are good that USB devices always start with a 'U', but the rest can be anything.

Comment: How do I establish which device is the keyboard? If I try "lsusb" I get a list of devices, but they have different IDs. There's no "USB0" or anything like the /proc/acpi/wakeup lists as device IDs.