# How to determine which device is the USB keyboard in 18.04?

Tags: keyboard, suspend

Trying to follow the answer here:

[How can I wake up my PC with any key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205256/how-can-i-wake-up-my-pc-with-any-key)

There is a step which states:

> Once you have established which device is the keyboard lets say USB0 run this command.

How do I know which USBx is the keyboard?

Comment: How about you simply try out? There's no reason to believe the linked solution doesn't work until you have tried and it failed. Regarding finding which is the correct device, I guess trial and error is a legitimate approach here to.

Comment: What if it breaks the system...there have been many instances where I tried to temper with a Linux distro and which resulted in a broken system...Should I take that risk ?