# Is it possible to wake system from suspend using any keyboard key on integrated laptop keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, suspend, thinkpad, wakeup

As the title suggests, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to make my laptop wake from suspend using any key on my keyboard (the laptop keyboard, not an external USB one)?

I've tried the tips suggested here: [205256](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205256/how-can-i-wake-up-my-pc-with-any-key)

Unfortunately, this dos not work, since my integrated keyboard or touchpad do not appear here.

```
~$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LID   S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
IGBE      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
EXP2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.1
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
```

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T440 (i5 4300U) and I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Any help would be much appreciated!